# Very strange bug with textarea

Tags: javascript, css, html, textarea

My previous question was about the same crash, but in contenteditable element ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839595/custom-input-field-crash)). 
Moving forward I have discovered that the same things happens in textarea. 
In my example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AzEzEmU/6/edit?html,js,output)) you just have to simulate the situation like: you input 2 rows in that textarea then move your cursor somewhere in the middle of text and press enter subsequently the page would crash.
It seems like the complex of events that leads to page crash. Also this crash is similar everywhere not only in JSBin, fiddle or else.

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/AzEzEmU/6/edit?html,js,output)

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
console.log("ready");
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"), overflowOnce = true;/* , savedText; */

console.log(textarea);

textarea.addEventListener("overflowchanged", function() {
  if (overflowOnce) {
    console.log("overflowchanged");
    /* console.log("savedText " + savedText); */
    /* console.log("current text: " + textarea.value);*/
    textarea.value = "blabla"; 
    overflowOnce = false;
  }
  else if (!overflowOnce) overflowOnce = true;
}, false);


textarea.onkeypress = function (e) {
  console.log("press " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
  /* savedText = textarea.value;
  console.log(savedText); */
};
```

Comment: This one also works just fine for me in both Firefox and Chrome. What exactly do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: It occurs for me. Add two rows of text (using enter to go to the next line), click anywhere in the text you just created, press enter again. Page should crash (at least for me in Chrome)

Comment: With that being said, taking out the js removes the crash, so it's a problem with that

Comment: I've been clicking and typing in and out of the textarea, and nothing weird happens at all. (I'm using Chrome  29.0.1547.62 on Linux.) *edit* - oh wait it just happened. I'd log a bug, as that's clearly what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why, but, if you change `textarea.value = "blabla";` to this `setTimeout(function(){textarea.value = "blabla";},1);` the crash stops.

Comment: same solution works with most ajax forms BTW (I mean they have trouble with accessing content exactly after loading it, only setTimeout helps, so maybe it's the same issue)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it solves this problem. It will be awesome if someone could explain what happens underneath.

Comment: @VadimKalinin in my opinion, a complete page crash caused by something that simple is just a runtime bug in Chrome (or WebKit or whatever). Firefox doesn't have a problem with it, and there's nothing overtly wrong with the code.

Comment: @Pointy Interesting that in firefox overflow event triggers only first time. Then i can't trigger it.